# QSFP28 DAC cables causing packet loss and framing issues

Tags: juniper

So the systems I am using are MX960 MPC7e.

When I use the 1meter 100G DAC I have zero errors + zero packet loss.

When I use the 3meter 100G DAC cables I have packet loss & framing errors.  I tried 3 DAC cables on 2 different sets of routers…all MX960 MPC7e.

These are 3rd party DAC cables, all from the same place, but what I do not understand is why the 1M cables work and the 3M are giving me errors. The only difference between the cables that I have noticed is that the 3M are 28AWG and the 1M are 30AWG.

Any ideas as to what the issue is? I would think it was just a bad cable, but all 3 of them seems a little strange.

Comment: Cheap substandard cables are common.  It would be far stranger to me if you tried 3 from all different places and they all had the same behavior but at least that would indicate it might not be the cables.

Comment: Been using this vendor for years, going through hundreds of the same DAC without issues, until these three Juniper ones... That is why I find it strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this issue was not only because of the length and gauge of the cable but also the design of the PCBs in the transceiver end. Switching to a 26AWG cable improved the performance of the cable enough to get rid of these errors.

Different gauge cables can still be used but would need to acquire them from a different source that has improved PCB.